# How to get public master key of a Ledger wallet?

Tags: public-key, bip32-hd-wallets, ledger-hardware-wallet

I have a ledger Nano S and would like to know how to extract the public master key of its wallet, in order to do HD key derivation in an external process.

Is there a way or is this info never exposed in any way?

Answer (score 4):

Find the HD Public key for your wallets:

1. Open the Ledger Wallet Chrome bitcoin app
2. Click your account in the overview, it’s called “My account” by default
3. Click “Account Settings” in the top right corner, under the balance
4. Click “Export” next to “Extended public key”
5. And when you see the QR code pop, you’re ready to begin the next part.

You can test the address by going to:
https://blockchain.info/xpub/123XYZ where `123XYZ` is your public key. You should see your transactions and balance.

Credit: https://keepingstock.net/storing-your-cryptocoins-in-a-bank-with-a-ledger-wallet-52d7895b9dd